# Filename of Solaris 11 (11.0)?

Tags: solaris, iso

I'm trying to find a download-link for the first version of Solaris 11 ie. 11.0, but I'm unsure of what it was called - eg. sol-11_0 , sol-11 , or something else?
For comparison, the 11.1 was called sol-11_1-text-x86.iso (and sol-11_1-live-x86.iso), and this convention has been used since, including the current 11.4 (sol-11_4-text-x86.iso).

Comment: I think the first version  was Solaris 11 Express 2010.11,  sol-11-exp-201011-text-x86.iso

Comment: Solaris 11 Express was the beta version.

Answer (score 2):

The first non-beta release was named "Solaris 11 11/11", continuing the release date style from Solaris 10, before switching to the more common dotted version style for Solaris 11.1.  Filenames were in the form `sol-11-1111-live-x86.iso`.